# Send audio over socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, audio, network-programming, portaudio

I am trying to send audio to a server that I built through a socket. I am using C for the client. Basically my code records a max of 10 seconds of audio and then I want to send it to my server through a socket. How can I send the audio that was recorded through a socket in C? I don't want to save the audio as a file... I want to send it directly to the server.

Here is my code:

```
// Standard libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

// Audio libraries
#include "portaudio.h"

// Audio parameters
#define RECORD_AUDIO_THRESHOLD 0.003
#define SILENCE_SECONDS 1
#define MAX_RECORDING_SECONDS 10
#define AUDIO_FORMAT paFloat32
typedef float SAMPLE_TYPE;
#define NUM_INPUT_CHANNELS 1
#define NUM_OUTPUT_CHANNELS 1
#define SAMPLE_RATE 44100
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER 512

// Server details
#define SERVER_ADDRESS "127.0.0.1"
#define SERVER_PORT 8080

// Global variables
int sock = 0;

// ######################## Structures ########################

typedef struct
{
    int             recording;
    int             maxFrameIndex;
    int             currentFrameIndex;
    int             silenceStartFrameIndex;
    double          averageAmplitude;
    SAMPLE_TYPE     *recordedSamples;
}
paAudioData;

// ######################## Helper Functions ########################

void setup(void)
{

}

// ######################## Helper Functions ########################



// ######################## Callbacks ########################

static int paListeningCallback( const void *inputBuffer,
                                void *outputBuffer,
                                unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                                const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                                PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                                void *userData  )
{
    paAudioData *data = (paAudioData*)userData;
    const SAMPLE_TYPE *rptr = (const SAMPLE_TYPE*)inputBuffer;
    SAMPLE_TYPE *wptr = &data->recordedSamples[data->currentFrameIndex * NUM_INPUT_CHANNELS];
    unsigned long framesLeft = data->maxFrameIndex - data->currentFrameIndex;
    SAMPLE_TYPE amplitude, frameData;
    long framesToCalc, i;
    int j;

    // Prevent unused variable warnings.
    (void) outputBuffer;
    (void) timeInfo;
    (void) statusFlags;
    (void) userData;

    if (framesLeft < framesPerBuffer && data->recording)
        framesToCalc = framesLeft;
    else
        framesToCalc = framesPerBuffer;

    for (i = 0; i < framesToCalc; i++)
    {
        frameData = *rptr++;
        amplitude = frameData;
        if (amplitude < 0) amplitude = -amplitude; // ABS
        if ((amplitude - data->averageAmplitude) >= RECORD_AUDIO_THRESHOLD)
        {
            if (!(data->recording))
            {
                data->recording = 1;
                data->currentFrameIndex = 0;
                printf("Recording...\n");
            }
            data->silenceStartFrameIndex = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < NUM_INPUT_CHANNELS; j++) *wptr++ = frameData;
        }
        else if (data->recording)
        {
            if (data->silenceStartFrameIndex == 0) data->silenceStartFrameIndex = data->currentFrameIndex + i;

            if ((data->currentFrameIndex + i) == data->silenceStartFrameIndex + (SILENCE_SECONDS * SAMPLE_RATE * NUM_INPUT_CHANNELS))
            {
                data->recording = 0;
                data->currentFrameIndex += i;
                printf("Stopped recording.\n");

                // TODO: Send audio to server via socket

                return 0;
            }
            for (j = 0; j < NUM_INPUT_CHANNELS; j++) *wptr++ = frameData;
        }
    }
    data->currentFrameIndex += framesToCalc;
    return 0;
}

// ######################## Main ########################

int main(void)
{
    PaStream*           stream;
    PaError             err;
    paAudioData         data;
    int                 i,
                        totalFrames,
                        numSamples,
                        numBytes;
    struct sockaddr_in  address;
    int                 valread;
    struct sockaddr_in  serv_addr;
    char                buffer[2048] = {0};

    setup();

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER_ADDRESS, &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Initialize audio data
    data.maxFrameIndex = totalFrames = MAX_RECORDING_SECONDS * SAMPLE_RATE;
    data.currentFrameIndex = 0;
    numSamples = totalFrames * NUM_INPUT_CHANNELS;
    numBytes = numSamples * sizeof(SAMPLE_TYPE);
    data.recordedSamples = (SAMPLE_TYPE *) malloc(numBytes);
    data.averageAmplitude = 0;
    data.recording = 0;

    // Initialize PortAudio
    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if (err != paNoError) goto paError;

    // Open an audio listening stream
    err = Pa_OpenDefaultStream( &stream,
                                NUM_INPUT_CHANNELS,
                                0,
                                AUDIO_FORMAT,
                                SAMPLE_RATE,
                                FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
                                paListeningCallback,
                                &data  );
    if (err != paNoError) goto paError;

    // Start passive audio listening
    err = Pa_StartStream(stream);
    if (err != paNoError) goto paError;

    Pa_Sleep(10000);

    // Terminate PortAudio
    err = Pa_Terminate();
    if (err != paNoError) goto paError;

    // Print PortAudio error and exit
    paError:
        printf("PortAudio error: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
        return 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing special about sockets. Just `send` the data you want to send. You possibly want to send each frame as soon as you read it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude when I do `send(sock, data->recordedSamples, data->currentFrameIndex - 1, 0);` and I try to save the audio to a file in python on my server using `with open(wav_filename, 'wb') as wav_file: wav_file.write(data)` it doesn't work

Comment: Perhaps you should consider doing some exercises about sockets in general first? Maybe read a tutorial? Because unless `data->currentFrameIndex - 1` is the size of the data you want to send *in bytes* then it's not correct.

Comment: Also remember that TCP sockets are *streaming* (the `SOCK_STREAM` should be a hint about that) with no fixed start or end or boundaries between data. That means you might nor receive all that is sent in a single `recv` call, and you have to call `recv` in a loop.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I changed `data->currentFrameIndex - 1` to `(data->currentFrameIndex - 1) * sizeof(SAMPLE_TYPE)` which is the size in bytes... still no luck... do you know of any tutorials?

Comment: @NoahChalifour This is a nice and short tutorial: http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

Comment: when calling `send()` or `recv()`, remember that you may have to use a sliding window and call those functions in a loop to obtain all the data transfer.  When I last checked, the max per call was around 1700 bytes,  So would bode well if your code limited the length of each I/O operation to (say) 1600 bytes.

Comment: with typical sound sampling running around 40k samples per second (for high fidelity)  you can expect the communication with the server to fall behind the incoming sample rate, so suggest making a decision on how much (time wise) sound to sample, then pre-allocate a buffer large enough to hold all the samples.  Then send blocks of the samples in a loop.

Comment: in C, when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `(malloc, calloc, realloc), 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: the posted code has no ability to bypass the outputting of an error message, for instance when no error has occurred.

Comment: returning 0 from `main()` indicates that the program was successful.  However, when the program calls the `printf()` with `Pa_GetErrorText()` then an error has occurred.  When an error has occurred, a much better returned value would be: `EXIT_FAILURE` (from `stdlib.h`)  Also, error message should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`, so much better to use: `fprintf( stderr, "PortAudio error: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText(err) );`  When the error indication is from a system function, best to use: `perror()` so the text indicating why the system thinks the function failed is also output.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 0.003, 10, 512, 2048, 10000,  44100, 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the variable `sock`, currently declared in the file global space, is only used in `main()`, so should be declared in `main()`